# Django and selenium integration

Tags: django, selenium

I am trying to integrate my django app with selenium to run selenium tests by `manage.py test` command (I need something to automatocally run testserver).
Using [django-selenium](https://github.com/dragoon/django-selenium) for this integration.
When I run sample project from django-selenium, it going fine. But when I run the real app which use static files, I got this:

```
      File "env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py",
 line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django_selenium\selenium_server.p
y", line 45, in test_app
    return handler(environ, start_response)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handle
rs.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", li
ne 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", li
ne 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

  File env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", li
ne 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line
 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\views\defaults.py", line 3
0, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html templ
ate.
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line
157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line
138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

Looks like this is caused by static file handler....

How can I fix this error? DEBUG is True and I have static url handlers in urls.py

Comment: do you definitely have a `500.html` template?

Comment: I don't. But the problem is highter in the call stack. What is causing this HTTP 500 ?

Comment: if `DEBUG` (not `debEg`) were true it wouldn't look for 500.html, instead it would show you a page with an error description and a stack trace for the error (as opposed to a st for the missing template)

Comment: Definitely. This is the main point I don't understand. Why it looks for 500.html if debug is True. I don't know how django-selenium runs the testserver...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test server always runs with `DEBUG = False`; here's https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/ :

> Regardless of the value of the DEBUG setting in your configuration
>   file, all Django tests run with DEBUG=False. This is to ensure that
>   the observed output of your code matches what will be seen in a
>   production setting.

So you can't rely on the DEBUG handling of static files, you need an explicit production-like way of handling them for the test to find them. You could have a special section in your `urls.py` that turns on the development `serve()` for when you run `test`:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    static_url = re.escape(settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip('/'))
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % static_url, 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

Comment: I've set this, but the static files are not served, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not very much to go on. What happens instead? Do you have a previous URL pattern that could be capturing the static URL first?

Comment: Nope, I've checked it using the `show_url` command, and also I've checked `urlpattern` when testing, `/static/<path>` points to `django.views.static.serve`, but all the request returns 404.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. It definitely works for me, and as you can see is only a short piece of code that simply starts serving settings.STATIC_ROOT at your STATIC_URL if 'test' is in sys.argv. If  your STATIC_* settings are correct, then that's all it does.